# Document.write and ace editor

Tags: ace-editor, document.write

I tried to use the Ace editor in a document rewriting engine. The ace editor looks like this:

[image]

After running `document.write` which essentially rewrites the page, I get the following, but no error on the javascript console:

[image]

I cannot explain why I need document.write, I'm just trying to find a way to make this work. It looks like ace breaks itself after the page reloads.

Here is the Minimum Reproducing Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function loadAceEditor() {
        var aceeditor = ace.edit("aceeditor");
        aceeditor.setValue(document.getElementById("aceeditor").getAttribute("initdata"));
      }
    </script>
    <script id="acescript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.2/ace.js" async></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="aceeditor" style="width:100%;height:100%" initdata="test {}"></div>
    <script>
    onAceLoaded = (delay) => () => {
      if(typeof ace != "undefined" && document.querySelector("#aceeditor")) {
        loadAceEditor();
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.open();
          document.write(`
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="aceeditor" initdata="testended {}"></div>
    <script>
    onAceLoaded = (delay) => () => {
      if(typeof ace != "undefined") {
        loadAceEditor();
      } else {
        setTimeout(onAceLoaded(delay * 2), delay);
      }
    }
    onAceLoaded(1)();
    </${"script"}>
  </body>
</html>`);
          document.close();
        }, 3000)

      } else {
        setTimeout(onAceLoaded(delay * 2), delay);
      }
    }
    onAceLoaded(1)();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Edit

It has to do with the fact that `document.write` is called after ace.js is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually, the ace-editor was adding the following

```
<style id="ace_editor.css">...</style>
```

in HEAD the first time it's loaded, and not the second time. Reinserting this element made the trick.